# Visual prolog duplicates in list

Tags: list, prolog, element, visual-prolog

My task is to find most repeatable element in list on visual prolog. As I am beginner in prolog, I don't have any ideas how to do that. I have some examples like one below but I cant adapt it to Visual Prolog :(

```
listmax(L, M):-
   listmax(L, [], [], M).

listmax([], Seen, MMax, Max):-
   MMax=[] -> Max=Seen ; listmax(MMax, [], [], Max).
listmax([H|T], Seen, MMax, Max):-
   (  member(H, Seen) ->
      listmax(T, Seen, [H|MMax], Max)
   ;  listmax(T, [H|Seen], MMax, Max)
   ).
```

Comment: Although you're a beginner, what have they taught you about so far in class? If you need specific visual prolog Syntax help, I believe there's documentation online. Check PDC Prolog.

Comment: I know syntax a little bit, but I don't know how to do such task, so I found a solution but on a SWI Prolog. But for example I don't know how to do such thing in Visual Prolog : 
listmax(L, M):-
listmax(L, [], [], M).

Comment: A quick internet search turned up this link: [Visual Prolog Downloads](https://www.visual-prolog.com/vip/download/default.htm). You'll find documentation and tutorial links there.

Comment: I'd recommend you use SWI instead if you have the choice. Much more tooling, users, and help available with it, plus it is open source.